How to make a soundless world
I have an Earth-like planet where no sound can be propagated. Sound mediums are present like air and living beings exist to hear it but sounds are still muted.
Is there any possible way my planet can achieve this?

Is this the surface of a neutron star or somewhere even more exotic?

What is your goal behind having a soundless planet? I have some research I can share from when I was trying to evolve life that "heard" through an alternate method, but that might not help your vision if you need absolutely no sound.

@Yeslek71 I need a soundless world but you can share if you want. It might serve as inspiration

You might have to go with too much noise.There is constant white noise that masks the other sounds.

What precisely do you mean by sound?

If there is no sound, living beings would not evolve the means to hear sounds.

Sound means only is that small changes in the atomic structure propagate. Its existence is a very deep thing. Here is the world of imaginations, everything is possible, but creating a world where there is no sound et al would be probably an unimaginable change to the laws of the physics.

Yeah, what Futoque said. I would phrase it as the "noise floor" being so high that signals are indistinguishable from noise. It cheats by making it an utterly overwhelming amount of sounds, summed together, instead of being a lack of sound.

Clarification needed - do you need there to be no sound waves propagating, or do you need it to be impossible to hear the sounds, even if you have the ability to hear things normally? They have different solutions.

Can the people on this planet hear the words to 4'33"?

Would it count if the air pressure is (magically) so high that sound exists but just propagates at a snail’s pace?

sounds are still muted??? Please clarify this. Sound needs two things: 1. pressure waves propagating through stuff 2. living organisms equipped to perceive pressure waves in the surrounding medium, i. e. to operate as a microphone. Everything remotely akin to a celestial body (as in "Earth-like planet", moon, sun, asteroid, pebble in a planetary ring) has 1. Everyone on Earth (as in "every living organism, possibly excluding viruses if they're alive) has 2 to an extent.

The extent is that any microphone is unable to amplify waves of wavelengths clearly off its receiving band(s) and typically, these bands do not extend much beyond the diameter of the organism. Organisms do perceive harmonics of certain long-wavelength waves (to wit, we experience sea-sickness): at only a fraction of the transmitted power of the fundamental wavelength.

Since I don't have enough reputation on this stackoverflow site yet to submit an answer, I'll comment instead - I think what you have is a simulation (like the Matrix) that is indistinguishable from "reality".  The system designers simply didn't model sound in this (virtual) world.

There's a short story called The Year of Silence, by Kevin Brockmeier, that you might find interesting. It was on the NPR show Selected Shorts a really, really long time ago. I don't know if it's in print anywhere but it looks like you can buy that podcast episode.  https://store.symphonyspace.org/products/the-year-of-silence-mp3-download

Does this depend on who's listening? Is this, for instance, about whether when a tree falls in the forest and no-one is there to hear it, the falling tree makes a sound?
Failing even that, what might happen if on the world you describe, you clapped your hands or stamped your feet?

No, not really. Sound is produced by any interaction of matter with matter and/or energy: it's vibration of matter propagating through matter.
The only way would be for everything, I mean literally everything, to be perfectly still, or that you are talking about a matter-less world.

A gas-less world would be for the most part already be effectively soundless. Yes, technically there'd still be sound, but not in the way most people think about "sound". We're still not fully answering OPs question but at least there'd be some matter around

The former civilization of the world created a planet-spanning utility fog capable of providing virtually anything the inhabitants desired, primarily in response to verbal commands. This civilization became the former civilization when the main AI controlling the utility fog abruptly configured it to damp audible sounds and refused other attempts at communication.

Active Noise Cancellation on a planet scale. I like it.

Active Noise Cancellation on a planet scale. I like it.

I can imagine the situation where someone yells out loud, "I JUST WANT SILENCE!" Then no other sounds are ever heard again.  When someone tries to correct the mistake they realize that the utility fog ONLY responds to verbal commands and thus no one is able to command it to turn the sound back on since the commands are silenced.

Or the AI just decided that the problem of deconflicting and handling everybody's requests would be most effectively performed by preventing anyone from making requests. The massive drop in complaints afterward surely indicated that it was a wildly popular success.

@ChristopherJamesHuff this is exactly how an AI (with somewhat naive reward functions) will work.

Evolutionary pressures against hearing
If you have a medium for sound, you can't really have sound not happen. However, I think a more reasonable way to make this happen is to have a planet where there's an actual abundance of sound or loud noises, such that any hearing organs would be utterly desensitized. The actual source of this sound is up to you, although you'd probably want something that's relatively constant, such as extremely strong, loud winds probably loaded with particulates. Volcanic eruptions could probably produce enough loud noise but the quantity/frequency needed would probably make actually living there rather impossible.
The other potential option is biological, wherein you have a particular species or set of species evolve a means to produce loud noise, maybe to deter other animals, distract or disorient them. Basically deliberately producing so much auditory static that hearing is useless or even a nuisance to the animal, and thus potentially applying pressure to mute hearing. That said, this species would have to be pretty ubiquitous, and I'm not sure of the realism of this idea.
I think of these wind is definitely still your best option as a way to make hearing harder.

Good idea but unfortunately won't work. Even if sounds are generally loud, the ears will simply adapt. If there are loud noises, either ears will evolve to cancel their spectrums out, or brains will evolve to automatically subtract the typical spectral patterns of irrelevant noise. Even primitive brains can easily do this.

You could very well be right! But, I think you could still make an argument for muted perception. At least some amount of hearing would become heuristic, and in general if hearing is just that little bit harder to evolve, some species might prioritize other senses. In any case... I won't defend this too strongly as I'm not an expert, I just have ideas for how to meet an admittedly difficult criteria.

Sure, but brains as SO good at noise cancellation. Even to the point that we can deal better with speech that's interrupted by white noise than with speech interrupted by muting, i.e. we have actually evolved for a noisy environment. Detecting sounds from prey or predator is such a strong evolutionary factor that evolution will go to essentially any length to make use of it, there would be physical filtering and filtering by postprocessing.

That's fair enough. any major adjustment in sound would have to occur at time scales rapid enough that evolution wouldn't recoup them in time, which is... difficult. Do you suggest removing the post?

I cannot recommend any action, I know too little about the pros and cons of doing so on SE.

By the definition of sound (pressure waves that stimulate an "ear", which stimulates nerves that the brain then interprets), it's simple:
no ears... no sound.  Life on that planet just didn't evolve ears.
Darned inconvenient, though.  Predators would have a much easier job, and transmitting knowledge to successive generations become just as much harder (since speaking came before writing) a task.

Loud Flora
The ability to hear has only been evolutionarily useful for animals because we can use it to detect the movement of other organisms that are outside of the ability to detect by other means.  But what if the problem is not being able to hear, but being able to distinguish useful noises from the background.  Audio Processing Disorder is a condition in which a person can not hear important noises or understand speech over minor background noises, but with enough background noise, no animal would be able to distinguish useful sounds from the background; so, hearing would lose its utility.
But the good thing about a loud planet is that even non-native organisms would have their ability to hear badly dampened. As your brain tries to addap by blocking out the background noise, it will also be forced to block out most of the useful noise; so, even a human over time would start to be unable to hear anything... and if you stay too long, it might even make you go deaf from damage.
Why are the plants so loud?
On our world, plants evolved various toxins to ward off would be herbivores, but what if plants were instead able to emit loud noises when animals got too close.  These noises would scare off or deafen herbivores and attract alpha predators.  So, over time, plants and animals would co-evolve so that plants ruin the hearing of animals to give predators the advantage, and animals would evolve to ignore or be deaf to noise the same way many animals evolve toxin resistance so that herbivores could still eat.

Not at the world level, not within known physics at least.
All hope is not completely lost though, the beings who should be able to hear the sounds of the world could be defective though. The beings could have undergone some sort of physical change, Because Reasons™, that they are unaware of which has rendered them partially or wholly deaf, thus they are experiencing an eerily silent world for reasons they cannot understand. This change could be an artifact of the world itself, a biological or technological pathogen that damages everyone who lands, or it could be something in the journey to this world that has changed those who undertook it.

The only way I can imagine an Earth-like planet having no sound wave propagation and still having life would be to radically re-imagine what counts as “Earth-like” and “life.” For instance, an Earth-sized computing sphere full of digital life operating at near absolute zero temperatures. That may not be the way you want to go, and even with such a bizarre set-up, as long as there is matter and vibration there is likely to be some level of sound wave propagation.
It would, however, be possible to minimize sound or make it severely distorted compared to Earth. There are some fascinating analyses out there on the way sound behaves on different planets/moons in our solar system. Mars is among the quietest. As one write-up puts it, “You could be standing thirty feet from a shrieking banshee and hear next to nothing.” The problem here is having life, since the factors that make Mars quiet also make it more hostile to Earth-like life. According to NASA, they are:

Carbon dioxide: CO2 absorbs certain types of sound waves, particularly higher pitches, and it makes up about 96% of Mars’ atmosphere compared to 0.0391% of Earth’s. High CO2 levels do not necessarily lead to banshee shrieks going unheard, however. Venus has nearly the same percentage of CO2 and yet sound there would move faster than on Earth because…

Atmospheric density: Mars has a very thin atmosphere, 100 times thinner than Earth. This makes it harder for sound to propagate and results in a lower volume. The reason sound on Venus would be faster is because the high density of the atmosphere makes it behave almost like a liquid, which conducts sound better than (Earth) air.

Temperature: Sound moves slower in lower temperatures. Mars’ average surface temperature of -81° F/-63 C° drops the average speed of sound there to 540 mph compared to 760 mph on Earth. Sound that has to travel a long distance therefore lags or is lost sooner than on Earth.


All these factors are challenges for the survival of Earth-like life. We don’t do well with high CO2 or the level of cold you’d need to have a noticeable impact on sound. Having a thin atmosphere also makes it harder to breathe and increases the amount of potentially damaging UV radiation that reaches the planet’s surface. You might be able to get some mileage out of life that breathes or tolerates CO2, thrives in cold or under ice (which blocks UV), or has technology that allows them to survive these factors.

noise canceling effects
So, if you have the means to propagate a Wave, you have the means to transmit sound.
This represents a pretty significant hurdle.
However, Waves can be canceled out by an equal and opposite wave that is perfectly out of sync (or in sync depending on your perspective).
This is how noise canceling works - it doesn't stop the noise, it just creates an inverse sound wave and then the two cancel each other out.
How this would be done on a planet wide scale is where you, the world builder, would probably be best placed to say that it is a thing and no one really knows how it works.
Could be a phenomenon of geology (like a weird echoing cliffs), could be something to do with the atmosphere, could be a nano-tech thing. There are plenty of possibilities - but I think simply stating that waves are automatically canceled out is your best option.

Cliffs won't work, you'll have already heard the sound before you hear the echo. They'd only be able to cancel continuous sounds or those that repeat with precisely the right duration, and any such effect that cancels the sound at one point will reinforce it at others. You need something within the air itself canceling the pressure waves as they pass.

Not possible. Sound cancelling not only needs to be active, but also needs to be active for that one person in one place. For anyone else, anywhere else, the antiphase sound makes things louder. So no, there are precisely zero possibilities because it isn't physically possible.

noise cancellations is possible but only locally in designated places where the two sources are perceived in exact opposite phases. But in all surounding places, the two sources are in fact not in sync so their effect will start adding: when you're fatr enough from the synchronization place, you perceive almsot the sum of the two sources, as if they were just one, twice stronger. In other words: you have not canceled the noise, but moved it elsewhere, where there's now a stronger noise.

So effectively noise cancellation is all about dispersion of the sound outside a threshold radius. The challenge is then placing sound cancellation everywhere where existing sources are sounding undesired noise. This requires at least the same level of energy as all existing sources you want to cancel locally just to create a huge sphere or noise where all sound sources are dispersed and mixed, until they can no longer propagate (reduce the pressure and temperature in the outer sphere, this noise will fade out rapidly, and their frequency will shift down to unheard basses as small vibrations.

Now you have another difficulty: if the pressure and temperature is low outside, the sphere, such "cancellation" has th eeffect of increasing the pressure and temperatur inside, where sound sources will be shifted to higher frequencies and faster propagation. To cancel all sounds inside, this means increasing a lot the pressure and temperatur inside, and may be shift freuencies to unheard treble ranges, however living inside that sphere would be a nightmare to support biologically, in addition of energy consumtion and dispersion, producing high levels of gas emission: all would burn inside.

So to be able to live in this bubble, you would need to build a heat protection shell and live in a small bubble with lower but sustainable pressure and temperature. What you get is not lieving on Earth, but inside small shells with low interaction between each other, masking yourself from all others: you would live completely alone in these shells, living like in a small tomb. Seen from outside of this bubble, you're just looking like being litterally dead.

@verdy_p - interesting ideas - they should be an answer, not a comment :)

We can imagine then living in such protection shells, but keep our life interesting. But we would have to communicate withuot using sound, only light or radio, or other electric or magnetic fields. But we would also need to protect our needed resources, notably plants and animals as well! And avoid damaging collisions of all these life shells (otherwise we would suffer from impacts (i.e. acceleration levels largely above Earth gravity and in random directions) inside this "boiling Earth".

How such a planet look like? Probably like a very hot spongious material where all these solid shells are enclosed and sustained apart of each other, but with all the heat convection is actily driven in controled directions to the outside of the "planet" where it would radiate. The spongious material would look like melted rock, where we would live in. That spongious materiel would have billions of billions of bubbles of all sizes, to support life for out multicellular species, but as well for bacterias and virus that we depend for synthese of resources passing through solid protection shells.

Sound is an energy, let the plankton and other organisms consume it.
On your world plankton learned how to convert sound waves on top of light waves to energy effectively lowering sound propagation. Other mobile organisms could also travel to sound sources for feeding.
Of course this does not work in contact with sound source since object is not composed of sound eating organisms, but would work for sound propagated by air, water and soil if it contains enough organisms. Organisms could still communicate through sterile enough medium, but after some time flocks of sound eating organisms would make it harder.This would probably require huge density of plankton in atmosphere.

Is your world a dystopia?
In order to better force control on the lower caste, the elites have decreed (or perhaps a religious route to the same end) that all in the lower caste have their eardrums burst at a young age in order to enforce their place in society.
Possibly outer world visitors are required to wear earmuffs of some description
